# Relaxing a relation between variables if one of them reaches its maximal value

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming

I am trying to formulate an optimization problem that can be described as a set of tanks $T$ where each tank $t$ has a maximum capacity of $\overline{r}_{t}$. I want to fill all tanks as much as possible with a common resource $r$ (provided). However, the tanks should be filled according to a pre-defined weighting $\omega_{t}$, so e.g. one tank should always contain twice the resouces of another.

However, when a tank hits its maximum capacity $\overline{r}_{t}$ it should be excluded from this constraint. The remaining tanks should still adhere to the weighting. This is where I'm struggling, as I cannot fix the weighting-relationship between all tanks.

Example (in reality all variables are continuous):

- Tank1 has a capacity of 2 and a weight of 1
- Tank2 has a capacity of 10 and a weight of 1
- Tank3 has a capacity of 6 and a weight of 2

I expect the solution (resouces per tank) to be:

- [1,1,2] if $r=4$
- [2,2,4] if $r=8$
- [2,3,6] if $r=11$ (Tank1 is full and it's weighting does not need to match any more)
- [2,4,6] if $r=12$ (only Tank2 is getting filled from here)
- [2,10,6] for any $r \ge 18$

Any solutions I identified so far seem overly complex and very inefficient. Is it possible to formulate this problem as a linear program and if not, do you have any hints on how to solve this elegantly and efficiently?

Comment: I would suggest editing your question, as portions are unclear. You have symbols popping up undefined. Also, you refer to "progress", but there does not seem to be a time index.

Comment: Let's say that you start with three tanks and the weighting is 30%, 20%, 50%. If tank 1 hits its limit first, how do you want the weighting to change? Should tanks 2 and 3 now have weights 28.6% and 71.4% respectively?

Comment: thanks a lot for you reply! I removed a constraint which is not directly relevant to my main problem and made the description unclear. I also added an example of my expected behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let variable $x_t\in[0,\bar{r}_t]$ be the level of tank $t$, introduce binary variable $y_t$ to indicate whether tank $t$ is full, and introduce variable $z\in[0,r]$.  The following constraints do the job:
\begin{align}
\sum_t x_t &= \min\left(r,\sum_t \bar{r}_t\right) \tag1 \\
y_t = 0 &\implies x_t = \omega_t z &&\text{for all $t$} \tag2 \\
y_t = 1 &\implies x_t \ge \bar{r}_t &&\text{for all $t$} \tag3 \\
y_t = 1 &\implies \omega_t z \ge \bar{r}_t &&\text{for all $t$} \tag4
\end{align}
If your solver supports indicator constraints, you can use these directly.  Otherwise, you can use big-M constraints to linearize them.  For example, constraint $(3)$ becomes $x_t \ge \bar{r}_t y_t$.

Comment: This presumes (harmlessly) that $r \le \sum_t \bar{r}_t.$ When that is not true, you just fill all the tanks and waste the rest.

Comment: I think your comment and my update to $(1)$ happened simultaneously.

Comment: Great minds often think alike?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution and hinting me to indicator constraints! One question: Why do you use $\leq$ in $(3)$ when $x_t$ is per definition capped at $\bar{r}_t$? Would $=$ work as well?

Comment: I used $\ge$ in $(3)$ because $\le$ is already enforced as an upper bound on $x_t$. Yes, you can use $=$ in $(3)$ if you prefer.